# JavaScriptCore framework availability on iOS

Tags: ios, javascriptcore

I am using the JavaScriptCore framework that was [introduced in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW17). My app has an *iOS 6.0* deployment target. I am linking the app with JavaScriptCore.framework (which is by default in *required* mode). The new [JavaScript Objective-C classes](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html) (`JSContext`, `JSValue` etc.) are obviously not available when running on iOS 6 but I can still use the plain C API, i.e. `JSGlobalContextCreate()`, `JSObjectCallAsFunction()` etc.

If I link the MultipeerConnectivity framework which was also introduced in iOS 7 and I run my app on iOS 6, I get an expected crash at startup:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MultipeerConnectivity.framework/MultipeerConnectivity
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/5AB83411-CEFC-437D-88F8-6B80C36CCE9F/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

Why is my app not crashing with the same dyld error when I link the JavaScriptCore framework?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When linking the JavaScriptCore framework with an **iOS 7** deployment target the app links to `Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework`:

```
otool -L -arch armv7 MyApp 
MyApp:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 537.51.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2935.137.0)
    ...
```

When linking the JavaScriptCore framework with an **iOS 6** deployment target the app links to `PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework`:

```
otool -L -arch armv7 MyApp
MyApp:
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 537.51.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2935.137.0)
    ...
```

This is because the JavaScriptCore framework has [special symbols](http://twitter.com/gparker/status/463731984729001984) that instruct the linker to change its dylib install path depending on the deployment target version:

```
nm JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore | grep '\$ld\$'
00000000003959a0 S $ld$install_name$os4.3$/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
00000000003959a1 S $ld$install_name$os5.0$/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
00000000003959a2 S $ld$install_name$os5.1$/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
00000000003959a3 S $ld$install_name$os6.0$/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
00000000003959a4 S $ld$install_name$os6.1$/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
```

The JavaScriptCore framework is available in the `PrivateFrameworks` directory in iOS 4.3 to 6.1 so the app finds it there at startup. On iOS 7, `PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework` is a symbolic link to `Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework` so that the app can run on both iOS 6 and 7.

Although not documented anywhere, this was clearly a deliberate move from Apple to add backward compatibility to the JavaScriptCore framework. But unfortunately, the App Store validation team did not get the memo from the JavaScriptCore team and apps linking the JavaScriptCore framework and targeting iOS below 7 [will be rejected](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController/issues/39) because they are using a framework in the `PrivateFrameworks` directory. Please duplicate [rdar://problem/17076670](http://www.openradar.me/17076670) if you want Apple to solve this issue.

In the meantime, you can workaround the rejection by removing the JavaScriptCore framework from your project and using the following *Other Linker Flags* instead (adapt for each undefined symbol error you get)

```
-Wl,-U,_JSGlobalContextCreate
-Wl,-U,_JSGlobalContextRelease
```

This tells the linker to resolve the symbols dynamically. Since the JavaScriptCore framework is always indirectly loaded through UIKit → WebKit → JavaScriptCore, the symbols will resolve just fine at runtime and your app should not be rejected since it doesn’t explicitly link the JavaScriptCore framework anymore.

Comment: I bet there's also something to do with LGPL compliance in there as well.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that it has nothing to do with LGPL compliance, just a matter of SDK incompatibility.